# Extra section divisions inside SharePoint Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, promoted-links

I have two promoted links tile Web Parts on my SharePoint page.  For some reason, an extra border appears around one of these We parts and not the other, causing them to be out of line with each other when I exit the editor!  Very frustrating...  I'd appreciate some advice on either how to remove the extra border, or add it to the other side so I can get the two promoted links sections in line with each other.

[image: Extra box around the "EMS" promoted links not around the "Useful Links" part]

Comment: Try setting **Chrome Type** of both webparts to same value (either **None** or **Title and Border**). let me know if it works for you. Also, is this a wiki page or a web-part page (I think it is a wiki page)?

Comment: Ganesh, thanks for the response - both are already set to None for the Chrome Type - I didn't want the headers to show outside of the editing window! Unfortunately this didn't solve it!  How do I check the page type (bit of a SharePoint newbie I'm afraid!

Comment: I think there is a space/new line outside the actual webpart (left side webpart) on your page. Try clicking outside the border (box) where "EMS" is written and press **Delete** button from your keyboard (Note down or remember the webpart configurations in case actual webpart gets deleted).

Comment: Unfortunately this either does nothing or deletes the entire web part!

Comment: Or try adding similar new line or space above 2nd webpart to make them align at same line (Maybe changing font size by clicking on the blank space area). This may sound silly but it should work for you.

Comment: Ganesh,  I've now tried this editing the line above each of the promoted links parts and still can't get them to line up because of the border around the left hand links!